# Get the amount of records of a person of the last 5 years

Tags: r, data.table

I've the following `data.table`:

```
               CODE     ID           VALUE YEAR_MONTH  temp_YEAR_MONTH
      1:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206      1992-06-01                         
      2:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207      1992-07-01                         
      3:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208      1992-08-01                         
      4:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209      1992-09-01                         
      5:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210      1992-10-01                         
     ---                                                                                   
1012974:       DCBEZOND    88619     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012975:       ABOUDERE    90325     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012976:       ABOUDERE    91301     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012977:       ABOUDERE    91808     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012978:       ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711      2017-11-01
```

And what I would like to have is, an extra column which tells me how any times an ID appeared, this for the last 5 years... only (max 60)

E.G.

```
         CODE     ID           VALUE YEAR_MONTH  temp_YEAR_MONTH   APPEARANCES_LAST_5_YEARS
1:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206      1992-06-01        1  
2:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207      1992-07-01        2  
3:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208      1992-08-01        3      
4:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209      1992-09-01        4   
5:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210      1992-10-01        5
---
1012978: ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711      2017-11-01        60
```

The way how I did this was via:

```
dt$temp_YEAR_MONTH <- as.Date(paste(dt$YEAR_MONTH,'01'), format = '%Y%m%d')
dt$APPEARANCES_LAST_5_YEARS = 0

tmp.temp_YEAR_MONTH = dt$temp_YEAR_MONTH
tmp.ID= dt$ID

id_date_function <- function(id, date){
  sum(tmp.ID == id & tmp.temp_YEAR_MONTH < as.Date(paste(date,'01'), format = '%Y%m%d') & 
    tmp.temp_YEAR_MONTH  > as.Date(paste(as.numeric(date)-500,'01'), format = '%Y%m%d'))
}

print('this will take some time')
dt$APPEARANCES_LAST_5_YEARS <- 
  apply(dt, 1, function(x)  id_date_function(x['ID'], x['YEAR_MONTH']))
```

But this is very slow... for 1.000.000 records, it will take +13hours.
Does someone has a better method?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are you using a data.table without any data.table syntax (and thus inefficiently)? Have you studied the data.table vignettes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using a *range join* (*non-equi join*) and aggregating during join using `by = .EACHI`:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
DT[, mon := ymd(YEAR_MONTH, truncated = 1L)][
  , APPEARANCES_LAST_5_YEARS := 
    .SD[.(ID, mon, mon - months(5L * 12L)), 
        on = .(ID, mon <= V2, mon > V3), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][, mon := NULL][]
```

> ```
>         CODE       ID VALUE YEAR_MONTH APPEARANCES_LAST_5_YEARS
>  1: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206                        1
>  2: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207                        2
>  3: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208                        3
>  4: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209                        4
>  5: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210                        5
>  6: DCBEZOND    88619     1     201711                        1
>  7: ABOUDERE    90325     1     201711                        1
>  8: ABOUDERE    91301     1     201711                        1
>  9: ABOUDERE    91808     1     201711                        1
> 10: ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711                        1
> ```

Unfortunately, the sample data set provided by the OP isn't large enough to cover a 5 year's period. In order to demonstrate that only a certain period is considered, the period is restricted to 3 months for demonstration purpose:

```
DT[, mon := ymd(YEAR_MONTH, truncated = 1L)][
  , APPEARANCES_LAST_3_MONTHS := 
    .SD[.(ID, mon, mon - months(3L)), 
        on = .(ID, mon <= V2, mon > V3), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][, mon := NULL][]
```

> ```
>         CODE       ID VALUE YEAR_MONTH APPEARANCES_LAST_3_MONTHS
>  1: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206                         1
>  2: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207                         2
>  3: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208                         3
>  4: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209                         3
>  5: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210                         3
>  6: DCBEZOND    88619     1     201711                         1
>  7: ABOUDERE    90325     1     201711                         1
>  8: ABOUDERE    91301     1     201711                         1
>  9: ABOUDERE    91808     1     201711                         1
> 10: ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711                         1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("id               CODE     ID           VALUE YEAR_MONTH  temp_YEAR_MONTH
      1:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206      1992-06-01                         
      2:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207      1992-07-01                         
      3:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208      1992-08-01                         
      4:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209      1992-09-01                         
      5:       ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210      1992-10-01                         
1012974:       DCBEZOND    88619     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012975:       ABOUDERE    90325     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012976:       ABOUDERE    91301     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012977:       ABOUDERE    91808     1     201711      2017-11-01                          
1012978:       ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711      2017-11-01        ",
            drop = c(1L, 6L))
DT
```

> ```
>         CODE       ID VALUE YEAR_MONTH
>  1: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199206
>  2: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199207
>  3: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199208
>  4: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199209
>  5: ABOUDERE 12608095     1     199210
>  6: DCBEZOND    88619     1     201711
>  7: ABOUDERE    90325     1     201711
>  8: ABOUDERE    91301     1     201711
>  9: ABOUDERE    91808     1     201711
> 10: ABOUDERE    92866     1     201711
> ```